# How to open Star Micronics mPOP cash drawer using code

Tags: objective-c, sdk

I just received my mPOP device with printer ands cash drawer and I wanted to try and write a simple app to just open the cash drawer and write a log when it was opened and again when closed. I cannot find any easy documentation how to do this.

Can someone please help with the minimum code snippet to open the cash drawer and how to detect it was opened or closed?

Answer (score 1):

The drive drawer command is `ESC * r D [0|1|2|3] null`, you can find it in the Command Specifications manual. The programming documentation can be found in the document `StarIO_POSPrinter_iOS_SDK.pdf`. Both documents can be found in the [Star Micronics Developers Section](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx). The following snippet is taken from the second manual.

Byte #5 in the `command[]` array on line 1 of the snippet defines which drive should be activated, possible is `0x00` (none), `0x01` (drive 1), `0x02` (drive 2) and `0x03` (both drives).

This is as far as I get without testing, but maybe you find your way from there.

```
unsigned char command[] = {0x1B, 0x2A, 0x72, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00};
uint bytesWritten = 0;
StarPrinterStatus_2 starPrinterStatus;
SMPort *port = nil;
@try
{
    port = [SMPort getPort:@"BT:" :@"" :10000];
    //Start checking the completion of printing
    [port beginCheckedBlock:&starPrinterStatus :2];
    if (starPrinterStatus.offline == SM_TRUE)
    {
        //There was an error writing to the port
    }
    while (bytesWritten < sizeof (command)) {
        bytesWritten += [port writePort: command : bytesWritten : sizeof (command) - bytesWritten];
    }
    //End checking the completion of printing
    [port endCheckedBlock:&starPrinterStatus :2];
    if (starPrinterStatus.offline == SM_TRUE)
    {
        //There was an error writing to the port
    }
}
@catch (PortException)
{
    //There was an error writing to the port
}
@finally
{
    [SMPort releasePort:port];
}
```

Comment: The documentation is far from clear on what I need to include to get access to the functions, I have added the frameworks etc to my project but what file or framework do I #import in my .h file to get access to these functions like SMPort ?

Comment: I tried this with and without the path but still no luck, #import <starmicronics/Platform.h>

Comment: Download the IOS_SDK from starmicronics.com, it's built as a application template. Open _IOS_SDK.xcodeproj_ with _XCode_. Edit the file _IOS_SDKViewController.m_ , which is the app's starting point. All the required headers etc. should be ready for you to use.

Comment: I already have an existing app I cannot move my app i to the sdk template, I am sorry I am just very confused by this, I expected this to work as any other lib I have integrated into my app like zbar, iZettle etc but this really has me head spinning, I want to add the frameworks to my own app and get the functions available in my app

Comment: I don't have a printer so I can't help any further. I would start at the app template and make it work, then strip everything out that's not needed. In the end you'll have a minimal code sample that works, and it will be easier to add to your existing project. Good luck buddy...

Comment: Hey, did you get this yet, cuz I have been assigned to do the same task, and I came across your question. If you have done it, can you please tell me how to do it.
Thank you!